# How do you force the iOS upgrade dialog (and other Apple dialogs) to dismiss before running CI tests?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-ui-automation, calabash, calabash-ios

Every time there's a minor/major OS update available, Apple displays a dialog on our CI iPad (physical device). I believe I have also seen one that is something like "you have not backed up in 2 weeks". Those dialogs block our automation and it makes us look bad when we have no test results. Are there any tools or tricks we can use to dismiss/prevent those dialogs?

Currently we are running iOS 9.

Comment: @jmoody what do you do for your CI tests?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 UI testing does that for you (don't mix it up with ui automation)
The drawback is - it runs only on ios9 and up.

Comment: I tried launching Instruments and starting a session, but even Instruments couldn't make it past a push notification dialog

Comment: You supposed to run tests, not instruments. Have a look at WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/

Comment: Ah interesting, I assumed they changed the API within Instruments. I will check that out and reply here.